# FrameBuffer texture breaks after changing device language

Tags: android, libgdx

I am happily using libgdx for an android game application.

At a specific point in the game, I use a FrameBuffer object to render the screen onto, and then use its attached color texture for rendering that to the screen (to be able to render a half-transparent screen with full-color rectangular zones).

The documentation for FrameBuffer says:

> FrameBuffers are managed. In case of an OpenGL context loss, which only happens on Android when a user switches to another application or receives an incoming call, the framebuffer will be automatically recreated.

And that works perfectly, I can switch to other applications, put the device in sleep mode, go back to the application and everything including the framebuffer is working as usual.

The problem begins when I try and change the device's language when the application is running (using the android settings menu).
After I change the language to something else, the framebuffer attached texture becomes completely black (either the rendering to it fails or its rendering to the screen does).

The incredible thing is that, even if I restart the application (i.e. the application reaches its onDestroy() method and exits), the problem does NOT go away, and it does only when I kill the application process from the task manager.

I probably could solve this by adding a System.exit(0) inside the onDestroy() method, but does anyone have an idea about what exactly happens when I change the device language?

I cannot think of any possible relation between that and the framebuffer object state (the other textures are working as usual!), if anyone could enlight me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you writing text onto the FrameBuffer? Might want to submit a bug report to the libgdx project. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues

Comment: May be your `FrameBuffer` is a `static` field?

Comment: Yes it is a static field, does it matter? According to the documentation the state is "managed", I also checked the implementation within FrameBuffer class and it seems alright to me...  I really do not understand the difference between 'quit and re-enter the application' and 'change the language of the device, restart the application'... I guess there is some android weird behavior going on when you change the language, but I cannot find any documentation for that... Thanks for your help, it's really appreciated^^

Comment: Tenfour04> I am rendering text and images on the frame buffer, but none of them is visible after I change the device language while the app is running until I completely kill the app with the task manager.
I temporarily solved the problem by adding System.exit in the onDestroy method of the activity, but I know this is not a good practice.  I may file a bug to gdx, good point.

Comment: Since it's in a static field, exiting the Activity will not kill it -- so you don't need to to do that System.exit(0) trick if you just don't reference it in a static field.  I think this might be your problem with the language as well. Perhaps changing the language makes Android close Activities and reload them, but since your Texture is in a static field, it is referring to something from the closed Activity, not the new Libgdx engine that is recreated when the Activity restarts. "Managed" textures can only be managed within a single Libgdx engine. Static references mess up that system.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.
To be honest, by going through the FrameBuffer object implementation, I can see that the instances are just store internally in a map, and never replaced, so when the application is restarted, the contents are modified but the reference is the same... It should not matter in that case wether I keep the reference in a static method or not, is this my misunderstanding of something? I probably just don't understand how this "close activity and reload" system works...

Comment: As incredible as it sounds, it turns out that you are right, only by moving the static reference to a non-static singleton class instance the problem *seems* to have disappeared.  I still don't quite understand the reason for this^^